# Specification pattern vs Always valid domain model

Tags: c#, design-patterns, .net, ddd

Let's say we have two aggregates:

```
public class Order : IAggregateRoot
{
    public Address Address { get; private set; }
    
    public int? BuyerId {get; private set}

    public OrderStatus OrderStatus { get; private set; }

    public string Description {get; private set;}
}
```

and

```
public class Buyer : IAggregateRoot
{
    public string IdentityGuid { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<PaymentMethod> PaymentMethods => _paymentMethods.AsReadOnly();
    
    public bool IsActivated { get; private set; }
}
```

and we want to allow only activated user to create an order.
**Should this logic be inserted in domain service or in specification pattern like this (and how this will affect always valid domain model state):**

```
interface ISpecification {
    bool IsSatisfiedBy(Offer offer);
}
```

```
public class OrderSpecification : ISpecification {
    private Buyer _buyer;
    public OrderSpecification(Buyer buyer) =>
        _buyer = buyer;

    public bool IsSatisfiedBy(Order order) => buyer.IsActivated 
...
}
```

and then in order

````
    public Order(..., ISpecification spec) {
        // field initialize and then 

        if (!spec.IsSatisfiedBy(this))
            throw new OfferConstructionDomainException(...);
    }

```
````

Comment: This might be more on-topic over at [SoftwareEngineering](https://SoftwareEngineering.StackExchange.com/), but before posting there please [**follow their tour**](https://SoftwareEngineering.StackExchange.com/tour), and read [**"What topics can I ask about here?"**](https://SoftwareEngineering.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic), [**"How do I ask a good question?"**](https://SoftwareEngineering.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"**](https://SoftwareEngineering.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: There's at least one other option: have a dedicated `ActivatedBuyer` class that you need to create an `Order`. There can then be a Domain Service that can take a `Buyer` and give you an `ActivatedBuyer`  if the user is activated. It's kind of clunky in C# though.